# power automate return multiple response to virtual agent

Tags: power-automate, power-virtual-agents, multiple-results

I have a power automate flow that is triggered from a chatbot flow (as part of virtual power agent). The data being generated from power automate output is more than 256KB in size. So, my requirement is to split is data into 2 parts and return them parallelly to the chatbot. However, I am not able to figure out a way to produce multiple responses to the virtual power agent. I created 2 parallel branches each having a part of the data to return with a "Return value(s) to Power Virtual Agents" step. But, unfortunately, only one flow will execute that will return the result, the other flow does not get chance to complete.

Is there any way to return multiple responses from power automate to the virtual power agent

I created 2 parallel branches each having a part of the data to return with a "Return value(s) to Power Virtual Agents" step. But, unfortunately, only one flow will execute that will return the result, the other flow does not get chance to complete